# Get LoggedIn Customer Details in a custom module block

Tags: magento2, session, customer-session

I am trying to get the customer details from customer session. But I am not able to get it. Below is my code:

```
class Review extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $customerSession;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function getCustomer()
{
    if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        $customerId = 1;
    else
        $customerId = 0;
    return $customerId;
}
```

I have tried other solutions also. Like to get customer Id & Name. But I didn't find the solution. I have gone through the Github issues also. But there also I didn't find any solution.

If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: anyone who can help me get loggedIn customer details. I don't want to use **Cacheable = "False"** in layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    if(this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
        $customerId = 1;
    else
        $customerId = 0;
    return $customerId;
}
```

Also verify in layout file your block have **cachable="false"** if not please add it

Comment: Tried this before. But its not working. Its not getting session here.

Comment: @gaurav store cache is disable?

Comment: No, Cache is enabled. And don't want the solution by disabling the store's cache.

Comment: So that you need to add cachable="false" in layout for this block

Comment: Yes, I have added this. but its not working. I can't understand why.

Comment: change it `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` with `\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` add code in files `this->customerSession->create()`

Comment: @PrashantValanda using cacheble="false" is not recommended to use. Unless you don't care about performance of the website and want to disable cache in all pages

Comment: @MaxPronko Yes, thats why I was not using it. Do you have any other solution for it?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal already mention in comment use factory method

Comment: @GauravAgrawal do you really need to use session on PHP side? There is a good option to use JS for this purposes.

Comment: @MaxPronko Please tell me...I can use JS also.